# В БД две таблицы 'users, 'todo'. В методе контроллера уже реализовано добавление туду в бд. Как сделать добавление id 'users' в user_id 'todo'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
public function store(Request $request): JsonResponse
   {
    $todo = new Todo();
    $todo->description = $request->input('description');
    $todo->save();

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 200,
        'message' => 'Todo добавлен!'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Таблицы имеют связь один ко многим. Не могу реализовать добавление Id из таблицы 'users' в столбец 'user_id' таблицы 'todo'

Comment: Непонятно, по каким данным ты хочешь выбирать юзера из имеющихся в таблице. Если есть, например, имя - тогда надо по нему получить идентификатор с помощью соотв. SELECT в таблицу юзеров, и использовать возвращённое значение при создании записи в туду.

Comment: @Akina да там скорее всего чето типа `$todo->user_id = Auth()::user`, или как там в ларавеле текущего юзера получить. Ну или ИД юзера тоже в реквесте приходит.

Comment: @u_mulder, спасибо! ваш подсказка помогла решить задачу!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function store(Request $request) : JsonResponse
{
    $todo = new Todo();
    $todo->description = $request->input('description');
    $todo->user_id = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::id();
    $todo->save();

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 200,
        'message' => 'Todo добавлен!'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: спасибо! я сделал $todo->user_id = Auth::user()->id; так! вообщем задача решилась!